# How to set image as canvas background instead of having it fill color in Android Studio/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I have the color of the canvas working, it can fill the blueish color as the background of the canvas accurately. However, How do I now change this to fill a image as the background instead of the color. It seems to not work at all. I have bolded the part to which I have the color being set. All help will be appreciated!

private void draw(){

```
    if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {

        canvas= ourHolder.lockCanvas();

        **canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 26, 128, 182));**
        
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 231, 172, 104));

        canvas.drawBitmap(playerShip.getBitmap(), playerShip.getX(), ScreenY - playerShip.getHeight(), paint);

        for(int i = 0; i < numInvaders; i++) {
            if (invaders[i].getVisibility()) {
                if (uhOroh) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(invaders[i].getBitmap(), invaders[i].getX(), invaders[i].getY(), paint);
                } else {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(invaders[i].getBitmap2(), invaders[i].getX(), invaders[i].getY(), paint);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an object of the color class, can you use an object of the Graphics class? Set the background like so:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("background.jpg");
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    // Draw the previously loaded image to Component.
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

}
```

Comment: Can you show me where exactly to implement the code in the code I already have? That's would be really helpful!